# Dynamic url routing with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have something like that in my code

```
<ul ng-model="services">
   <p ng-repeat="item in items"><b>{{ item.name }}</b> 
   </p>
```

I have for example 3 items: BMW, golf and mercedes
I want to have an url with the name of each item, like /bmw or /mercedes and all url use details.html to show the details of the selected Item. 
I'm trying to understand how can I do this.

Comment: Which router are you using? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

You can write a generic route like

```
.when('/car/:carId', {
  templateUrl: 'some/path/details.html',
  controller: 'someCtrl'
})
```

And then in the controller you can get the value of `:carId` using the [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to code this :

```
<ul ng-model="services">
  <p ng-repeat="item in items"><a href="/items/{{item}}">{{ item.name }}</b> 
  </p>
</ul>
```

And then capture the url in your app.js just like below:

```
.when('/item/:itemName', {
  templateUrl: 'some/path/itemDetail.html',
  controller: 'ItemCtrl'
})
```

And then to finish, you just need to get the item name in your controller

ItemCtrl.js :

```
App.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.itemName = $routeParams.itemName;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define paths within your module like so:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$mdThemingProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/page1', {
                    templateUrl: "Views/Angular/Pages/page1.html",
                    contoller: "page1Ctrl"
                })
                .when('/page2', {
                    templateUrl: "Views/Angular/Pages/page2.html",
                    controller: "page2Ctrl"
                })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/default' });
```

When the path is changed to 'page1' this module will load `page1.html` as the new view.

You can set up a view in an element such as:
`<md-content ng-view=""></md-content>`