# Dynamically routing url path in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, routes

I was wondering, is there a way to dynamically route the user to a specific page based on a certain parameter? For example, I may have a url that look something like this:

`http://localhost:8080/admin/{{id}}/home-page.html`

Here are examples of how I would want it to look like:

`http://localhost:8080/admin/13/home-page.html`

`http://localhost:8080/admin/9/home-page.html`

And based on each URL, I would navigate the user to the home-page.html file, but the data displayed on home-page.html would differ based on which id I pass in. I tried to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30874018/1871869 as a guide but I can’t seem to figure out where to put the `$routeParams`  `when` code because unless I create another controller/page prior to `home-page.html`, only then can i perform the redirection. Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `$routeProvider` you can use  :param

So for your URL about you could do

```
.when('/admin/:ID/home-page.html')
```

in your `$routeProvider`. Then `ctrlAs.ID` will be the value of your route.

If you add a question mark at the end, then that route parameter becomes optional, i.e.:

```
.when('/admin/:ID?')
```

will work with `localhost:8080/admin` or `localhost:8080/admin/15`

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://websystique.com/angularjs/angularjs-routing-tutorial-using-ngroute/) might help you. Please look into this.